# What's the meaning of "I found myself in a Voltairian position"

Tags: meaning

It was about someone defending a group of people and at some point, he said the expression "I found myself in a Voltairian position", what's the meaning behind that? I have read about Voltaire and I didn't find any reference to why might someone say such a sentence.

Comment: More context is needed.

Comment: "I disapprove of what you say, but I will defend to the death your right to say it"  is often misattributed to Voltaire, but is considered characteristic of Voltaire. The person doing the defending may have found themselves defending the right of others to say things they didn't agree with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaker: Voltaire?  [shmoop](https://www.shmoop.com/quotes/disapprove-of-what-you-say-defend-your-right-to-say-it.html)

> "**I disapprove of what you say, but I will defend to the death your
>   right to say it.**"

B. E. Hall, writing in her ~ 1900 biography, meant to **sum up** Voltaire's attitude towards freedom of expression, not quote him directly. But, because she put his words in quotation marks, she caused confusion.

This **Voltairian position or stance** is one that the biographer attributed to Voltaire, a vigorous defense of free speech.